# transform a list of string to list of tuples using foldl function

Tags: haskell, purescript

I have the below function :

```
fn :: [String] -> [(a,b,c)]
fn lst = case lst of
  [] -> []
  (a:b:c:xs) -> (a,b,c) : fn xs
```

I want to write this function using `foldl` or `foldr`

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: folds can replace recursions which consume one list element each time in a natural way. Here, you are consuming three, so it's cumbersome to use  a fold for this. Finally: 1) did you realize that your program will crash unless the input list does not have a length which is a multiple of 3? 2) your function has the wrong type, it should return a triplet of strings.

Comment: thanks for clarifying when `fold` function can replace recursion, regarding the point `1`and `2` you are completely right, the real function signature is `[String] -> Maybe [(String,String,String)]`, I have included this example to make it simpler. I think using this signature handle both points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write this function using `foldl` or `foldr`

This is somewhat ugly, but it technically solves it with `foldr` (it would be easy to adapt it to `foldl`):

```
fn :: String -> [(Char, Char, Char)]                                                                                                                                                                    
fn s = snd $ foldr toTriples ([], []) s where
    toTriples :: Char -> (String, [(Char, Char, Char)]) -> (String, [(Char, Char, Char)])
    toTriples c (cur, tups) | length cur < 2 = (c:cur, tups)
    toTriples c (cur, tups) = ([], (c, cur!!0, cur!!1):tups)
```

As the accumulator, it uses a pair of `cur`, the current part of the tuple being scanned, and `tups`, a list of tuples.

- If the length of `cur` is less than 2, it prepends the current character to it.
- If the length of `cur` is 2, it creates a tuple and prepends it to the list of tuples.